# How to combine two methods of System.out.printf operators?

Tags: java, printing, printf, system

So, I want to combine two operators of the printf-method in one. I want to save space of 10 spaces for the `value1` and round this variable to two digits after the comma IN ONE.

```
System.out.printf("%10s %.2f", value1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. What did you try and research? "I want is not a good beginning..."

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to print a float that should take up a total space of 10 characters and print two digits after comma only.

This should do your job:

```java
System.out.printf("%10.2f", value1);
```

The %s would be for printing Strings and not to give you spaces.